# Where in the 0.02066? (Bowtie antennas)

Tags: antenna, design, modeling

I'm relatively new to EE and antennas, but no stranger to RF analysis. After reading through [many](https://www.elprocus.com/bow-tie-antenna/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20a%20Bow%20Tie,as%20a%20bow%2Dtie%20antenna.) [different](https://www.eeweb.com/slotted-bowtie-antenna/) [articles](https://www.rfwireless-world.com/calculators/Bowtie-Antenna-Calculator.html) on Bowtie antennas, I'm at a loss as to where the value of 0.02066 comes from in the equation `D = 0.02066 * lambda`. Any suggestions, references, or derivations would be helpful! For instance, here's an image and text I typically find:

[image]

Comment: It's probably some combination of conversion factors and physical constants with the units stripped off. For some reason RF people love to just ignore units.